# How to upload database to google gmail

Tags: android, gmail, android-room, google-drive-android-api, android-backup-service

I want to save app database to gmail with the following tutorial  :
[Backup of Room Database files in Android | REST API v3](https://medium.com/@mkrs2404/backup-of-room-database-files-in-android-rest-api-v3-19a228dcecdf)

When I want to upload the database with the following code:

```
private void upload(){
    File storageFile = new File();
    storageFile.setParents(Collections.singletonList("appDataFolder"));
    storageFile.setName("classmanager");

    File storageFileShm = new File();
    storageFileShm.setParents(Collections.singletonList("appDataFolder"));
    storageFileShm.setName("classmanager-shm");

    File storageFileWal = new File();
    storageFileWal.setParents(Collections.singletonList("appDataFolder"));
    storageFileWal.setName("classmanager-wal");

    java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File(dbPath);
    java.io.File filePathShm = new java.io.File(dbPathShm);
    java.io.File filePathWal = new java.io.File(dbPathWal);
    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("",filePath);
    FileContent mediaContentShm = new FileContent("",filePathShm);
    FileContent mediaContentWal = new FileContent("",filePathWal);
    try {
        File file = googleDriveService.files().create(storageFile, mediaContent).execute();
        Log.i("TestGoogleDrive", "Filename: " + file.getName() + " File ID: " + file.getId());

        File fileShm = googleDriveService.files().create(storageFileShm, mediaContentShm).execute();
        Log.i("TestGoogleDrive", "FilenameShm: " + fileShm.getName() + " File IDShm: " + fileShm.getId());


        File fileWal = googleDriveService.files().create(storageFileWal, mediaContentWal).execute();
        Log.i("TestGoogleDrive", "FilenameWal: " + fileWal.getName() + " File IDWal: " + fileWal.getId());

    }
    catch(UserRecoverableAuthIOException e){
        Log.i("TestGoogleDrive"," UserRecoverableAuthIOException");
        startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), 1);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.i("TestGoogleDrive"," Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But It didn't work and got below error :

```
2022-02-22 09:25:46.201 20037-26860/? I/TestGoogleDrive:  Exception
2022-02-22 09:25:46.201 20037-26860/? W/System.err: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
2022-02-22 09:25:46.202 20037-26860/? W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
2022-02-22 09:25:46.202 20037-26860/? W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
```

Comment: Gmail? your using google drive api where does gmail come in to play exactly?

Comment: Please edit your question and include your authorization code where are you creating googleDriveService

Comment: Would you consider providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?